# Was Narcos shot on location?

Tags: film-location, narcos

The show features scenes from many places in Colombia, most notable Medellín but also Bogotá and Cali, as well as brief interludes from Chile/Peru and Panama.

How much of the South American scenes from Narcos were actually shot there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere between [most](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/arts/television/colombias-medellin-embraces-netflix-biopic-on-pablo-escobar/article26034610/):

> The biopic promises to be an authentic portrayal of Escobar, so it’s only natural that Brazilian director and **executive producer Jose Padilha chose to film the 10-episode series in Medellin, Colombia**, the murder capital of the world during the drug kingpin’s heyday in the 1980s.
>
> Filming the series here would have been unthinkable a few years ago, with Colombians still blaming Escobar for their country’s hard-to-shake association with drug trafficking. But as memories of Escobar’s terror campaign fade, and with the homicide rate at a decade low, Colombians are starting to view their violent past more dispassionately. ***So much so that cinema-loving President Juan Manuel Santos agreed to pick up $2-million (U.S.) in production costs so Netflix could film in the country***.

[and all of it](http://www.torontosun.com/2015/06/29/netflixs-narcos-takes-streaming-giant-into-new-territory):

> BOGOTA, Colombia - ***Outside of the big house, crew members pull up their hoods, trying to stay warm against the drizzle and wind coming off of the Andes mountain range in La Calera, a town 10 kilometres northeast of Bogota.*** ... Inside the big house, two actors glance down at a board game, getting into character as the director begins filming the scene. A third actor walks into the room - Brazilian star Wagner Moura, sporting a moustache and looking much heavier than his appearances in Elite Squad (2007) or Elysium (2013). Moura steps forward and quietly speaks Spanish to the other actors. This is a serious scene here, possibly a hostage situation, and he's showing a number of emotions on his face, looking a lot like the complicated man he's signed up to play - Colombian drug lord, Pablo Escobar.
>
> And now, nearly three years later, both men are set to release the 10-episode first season from a production that brought them across Colombia - including a meeting with Colombian President Juan Manuel Santos - **with film shoots also taking place in the U.S. and Panama**. [Executive Producer] Newman hopes the series can become a multi-season project, as the plot traces the effects of the drug trade into present-day.

Narcos filmed on location in Bogotá, Medellín, Panama and the U.S. *Not sure about Chile or Peru. And no mention of shooting in Calí.*

[Some more info:](http://www.thelocationguide.com/blog/2015/08/ng-television-pablo-escobar-netflix-miniseries-narcos-uses-colombia-filming-incentive/)

> ***Netflix worked in Bogota with Colombian production service company Dynamo.***
>
> Escobar himself is played by Brazilian actor Wagner Moura ... **“I flew to Medellín and stayed there six months before the rest of the cast and before I even signed with Netflix.** I booked myself in a university for a Spanish course for foreigners, and I think I’ve read basically everything that was written about Pablo Escobar and modern Colombian history.”